# PasteSpecial (Format and Values) on Destination Range

Tags: excel, vba

Good Day!

I just want to know if somebody could correct my could correct my code as I need to  have the format and value of the table I copied to retain the format when I paste it on the destination range. below is the code that I think I need to modify.

```
If lngIdx = 1 Then
        lngDstLastRow = 1
        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
    End If
    rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst '<~ this is the copy / paste

   'The Code below does not work at all as it throw an error

    With ActiveSheet.rngDst
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
       .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   End With
```

Thanks in Advance,
Yeojz

Comment: `Destination:=rngDst` destination is not needed i think.  Also, i think the destination needs to be like `range("a1:a100")`

Comment: The format in question belongs to the table - not the cells.

Comment: yes you are correct it is on the table with some merge cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to paste both values and formats why not:

```
With ActiveSheet.rngDst
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

Comment: tried this also but same result still the table is not formatted, thanks.